# Can't split string in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have trouble with the split function in Java. When I try to split a string with a regex "$"

```
String line = "Vu Quang Huy$2/11/1999$Ha Noi$Nam$CNTT$1.2$12$10000.0";
String[] properties = line.split("$");
```

It doesn't do any thing. The properties at index 0 is the same as the original string

```
System.out.println(properties[0]);
```

And it shows

```
Vu Quang Huy$2/11/1999$Ha Noi$Nam$CNTT$1.2$12$10000.0
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `line.split("\\$")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$` in regex means "the end of a string", use `\$` instead.

And, you have to escape the '\' as well, so you have to write it like this

```
String[] properties = line.split("\\$");
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks

Comment: it's ok. I can fix it. Thank you so much